# Large red stripes in negative scan

Tags: troubleshooting, scanning, negative-scanner, negative-film

I am using a HP G4050 Negative Scanner to scan some of my negatives and suddenly I started to get these strange type of blots, all my scanning are getting all blurred in red, already tried to change the cable, reset the scanner, reinstall driver. Some pictures are attached below to explain what I am saying. What can it be?

[image: Red stripes after scan]

[image: Negative picture of the scan]

Answer (score 3):

This kind of issue is usually given by some dust in the calibration area in the top of scanner plate.
A first try you can do to confirm it is to try to clean carefully that part and see if there is some change in the stripes pattern.
It shouldn't be cable related because the data are digitally transmitted and loosing of data didn't produce this effect but probably a simple error in communication.

Of course the dust could be not directly on the upper surface but inside, in this case you should disassemble and clean carefully (of course for this operation I suggest you skilled technician).

Comment: Hi Androx! Thanks for the reply. Actually the problem was with the Scan Software provided from HP, we changed to VueScan and everything works perfectly.